# How to pass arguments from tornado to a html file?

Tags: python, html, jsp, web, tornado

I have shared a part of my code and in the Class 'Room',variable 'nw' has the query string value.Now,I want the html file to autofill the 'nw' field with the query string value dynamically.How do I get that?Does self.get_namespaces help?

```
    class Room(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
       nw=self.get_argument("nw")
       print(nw)
       self.render("RoomPost.html")  

class static(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,key):
           iname="static/" +key
    print iname
              self.render(iname)        
settings = {
    'debug': True,
    'static_path': 'static'}

application = tornado.web.Application([

        (r"/room",Room ),

        #(r"/static/(.*)",static)
        ], **settings)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(5500)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Following is the html file

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static_url("css/registration.css")}} />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
<c:import url="InnerHeader.js"></c:import>
<br><br><br>

<center>
    <form action="/room" method="post" >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            <b1>Room Add</b1>
        </legend>
        <table class="registerTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Name of NW/Name of Home</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nw" placeholder="Kfx-Home"
                    maxlength="15" size="30" autofocus required/></td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" > &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                <input type="submit"     value="  Submit  " /></td>
                </tr>

        </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</center>
```

Comment: What's the point of JSP here? Why don't you use Python to serve the page?

Comment: Actually, are you sure you have JSP and not Jinja2?

Comment: But what you're posting here doesn't make sense. Tornado doesn't know how to render JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link helped me figure out the answer:

[How to pass arguments from tornado to a js file but not html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112296/how-to-pass-arguments-from-tornado-to-a-js-file-but-not-html).

I added self.render("RoomPost.jsp",nw=nw)  in tornado script and autofocus required value="{{nw}}" readonly/> in .jsp script.

Comment: You're only going to confuse yourself if you continue to think of your templates at JSP when they are clearly not.